# .rowconfigure does not expand?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am working on a fullscreen program, and the .columnconfigure works, but the .row configure doesn't?

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
root.bind("<Escape>",quit)
root.config(bg="black")
root.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2,weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(3,weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(4,weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(2,weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(3,weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(4,weight=1)
Label(text="hey").grid(row=0, column=1,sticky="WENS")
Label(text="hey").grid(row=0, column=2,sticky="WENS")
Label(text="hey").grid(row=0, column=3,sticky="WENS")
Label(text="hey").grid(row=0, column=4,sticky="WENS")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re always add your label in the row 0. But you configure row 1 to 4. Never the 0 one.

This is probably why it seems that rowconfigure doesn't work.